# Express the summation of the differences of all combinations of values by using the summation sign!

Tags: combinatorics, summation, notation

Say I have a set of m unique elements. Say, I also calculated the differences of the values for all combinations of those unique elements. How do I express the summation of those differences as a mathematical expression, that uses the summation symbol and two indices, one for each unique element?

Comment: Presumably you want something like $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m-1}\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^m|a_j-a_i|$ which represents $|a_2-a_1|+|a_3-a_1|+|a_4-a_1|+\dots+|a_3-a_2|+|a_4-a_2|+\dots$

Comment: Alternatively: $$\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq m} |a_j - a_i|.$$

Comment: @JMoravitz I saw your comment yesterday in a number theory question, it was about the rules of this site. What has changed from yesterday to today ?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks alot @JMoravitz